# How do I use audio tag to play the next "player" when song has finished

Tags: html, audio, tags, html5-audio

I have [this](https://elijahlucian.blogspot.com) blog where I post musical sketches. Now I use the HTML5 tag for audio after switching from a clunky flash player that didn't work on phones...

Essentially I am trying to make it so the player searches for the next `<audio>` tag after it's done playing. Is this possible using blogger?

Would I need top end page access to load some kind of JavaScript?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. If there is something in your post that needs to be held confidential, raise a mod flag and you will be assisted.

Comment: I think this question was simply bad and is now heavily irrelevant. How can I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?
http://codepen.io/nickcolley/pen/fBwJs

```
//Grab all audio elenents
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
//Create listeners
for (var i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
    audioListeners(i);
}
function audioListeners(i) {
    audio[i].addEventListener('ended', function() { 
      this.duration = 0; 
      this.pause();
      audio[i+1].play();
    }, false);
}
```